# Bulk insert - catch all constraint errors

Tags: sql-server, validation, t-sql, bulkinsert

I am trying to collect all format and constraint errors contained in a file, using `BULK INSERT`. I want the exact line in the file for each error and an error description.

Currently, I am using the `ERRORFILE` option to collect all formatting errors contained in the file. That gives me what I need, but only for formatting errors.

I want to do the same with constraint errors. If I use the `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` option, I can catch the error but the bulk insert terminates. Is there any way for the bulk insert to continue inserting rows after a constraint violation is detected, so that I can collect all constraint errors?

I can do the constraint checking on the temp table where the rows are inserted (after the bulk insert is completed), but I don't want to follow this approach because:

1. I cannot get the exact line in file where the constraint
   violation is found and
2. For performance reasons since the file
   might contain millions of rows

**Update**

The input file is a tab delimited text file with 3 columns: ID, Name, Description

Below is the code that I am using to read/validate the file:

```
create table #MyTable (ID int not null, Name varchar(20) not null, Description varchar(60) not null)

alter table #MyTable add check (ID != 1)

begin try
  execute sp_executesql 'bulk insert #MyTable from ''' + @FilePath + ''' with (maxerrors = 1000,check_constraints,errorfile='''+@ErrorFilePath+''')'
end try
begin catch
-- Here I am logging the constraint validation error
end catch
```

The desired output is a table with all format and constraint errors found in the file. Currently I am getting all format errors in the specified `errorfile` and I bulk insert the `errorfile` to get the errors in a table with structure

```
RowNumber int, ErrorDescription nvarchar(max) not null
```

I want this table to contain all the constraint errors too, in addition to the format errors. Currently, the query terminates when the first constraint error occurs (because of the `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` behavior).

Comment: I guess you can loop through all rows of the file yourself and do each insert command in a try catch block. Its not going to be fast but with millions of rows nothing is

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to import hundreds of thousands of XML files, with each containing exactly one row. My approach was to get in the first step all files into the database and then doing checks on text length, constraints, value ranges, conversion issues... When following this approach you need to declare the datatypes of all columns as nvarchar(max) allowing all data to be stored savely in the temporary table. You will never know what you will get. This table contains all information you need to do your checks, to identify the erroneous records, transform and write the transformed data into the destination table with a single SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable1 ([ID] varchar(max), [NAME] varchar(max), [DESCRIPTION] varchar(max));
CREATE TABLE #MyTable2 ([ID] int not null, [NAME] varchar(20) not null, [DESCRIPTION] varchar(60) not null);

EXEC sp_executesql 'bulk insert #MyTable from ''' + @FilePath + ''''
--> I'm not so familiar wit the right syntax. I hope it is right. The point is, don't do any checks here.

SELECT 
    TRY_CONVERT([ID])
   ,[NAME]
   ,[DESCRIPTION]
   --,CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT([ID]) IS NULL AND [ID] IS NOT NULL        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CONVERSION_ERROR_ID]
   --,CASE WHEN [NAME] IS NOT NULL AND LEN([NAME]) > 20               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CONVERSION_NAME]
   --,CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] IS NOT NULL AND LEN([DESCRIPTION]) > 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [CONVERSION_DESCRIPTION]
FROM 
   #MyTable1
WHERE
      CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT([ID]) IS NULL AND [ID] IS NOT NULL        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 --
   OR CASE WHEN [NAME] IS NOT NULL AND LEN([NAME]) > 20               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 -- --> show only erroneous rows
   OR CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] IS NOT NULL AND LEN([DESCRIPTION]) > 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 --
   -- Insert additional checks concerning the not null settings  


INSERT #MyTable2 ([ID], [NAME], [DESCRIPTION])
SELECT 
    [ID]
   ,[NAME]
   ,[DESCRIPTION]
FROM 
   #MyTable1
WHERE
       CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT([ID]) IS NULL AND [ID] IS NOT NULL        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0 --
   AND CASE WHEN [NAME] IS NOT NULL AND LEN([NAME]) > 20               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0 -- --> Write only those rows to #MyTable2 where no issues can be found
   AND CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] IS NOT NULL AND LEN([DESCRIPTION]) > 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0 --
   -- Insert additional checks concerning the not null settings  

-- Please note, that I have not tested these statements
```